# IActionFilter - why don't to have to implement all methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a custom action filter in a MVC web project. My custom action filter is as follows:

```
public class RequestLogFilterActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Code...
    }
}
```

How come I don't have to implement the OnActionExecuted method?

```
void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
}
```

Normally, you have to implement all methods in an interface. I don't get any build errors when building my project.

Comment: Because `ActionFilterAttribute` implements them all.

Comment: No - my class above does not implement the method OnActionExecuted. It only implements OnActionExecuting.

Comment: @thd My bad, I didn't notice the subtle difference in their names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How come I don't have to implement the OnActionExecuted method?

Because the base class, `ActionFilterAttribute`, has a matching `OnActionExecuted` method.

When you implement an interface, inherited members can be used to satisfy the interface.